# Недопонимание с указателями в структурах (пример из сетевого программирования)

Tags: c, указатели, структуры, сетевое-программирование

Для тех, кто знает сетевое программирование, переходите в конец, там сами вопросы. Для других немного поясню ниже.

(хоть мой вопрос и не касается сетевого программирования, я буду использовать пример именно из данной темы, чтобы не ошибиться при постановке вопроса)

Есть функция, которая возвращает указатель на структуру:

```
struct hostent {  
        char *h_name;
        char **h_aliases;
        int h_addrtype;
        int h_length;
        char **h_addr_list; // массив, содержащий адреса всех сетевых интерфейсов
    };

struct hostent *gethostbyname(const char *host_name);
```

Помимо этого имеется еще одна структура, которую мы будем использовать позже

```
struct in_addr {
        unsigned long s_addr;
    };
```

и функция, которая нам тоже понадобится

```
char *inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in) // конвертирует целочисленный тип в айпи-адрес стандартного вида (с точкой)
```

Итак, наша цель - узнать ip  хоста, для этого делаем следующее:

```
int main(void){

struct hostent *test; // указатель на структуру hostent
struct in_addr **making; // ?
int i = 0;
char buffer[17]; /* буфер для хранения айпи-адреса в стандартном виде */

test = gethostbyname("www.google.com"); /* теперь test - структура типа hostent */

making = (struct in_addr **) test->h_addr_list; // ?
    for(i = 0; making[i] != NULL; i++){  // ?
        strcpy( buffer, inet_ntoa(*making[i]));  // ?
    }
    puts(buffer); // выводим наш айпи адрес в стандартном виде с точкой


return 0;

}
```

Собственно мои вопросы:

1) Как все же правильно прочитать запись ниже?

```
struct in_addr **making;
```

Указатель на указатель на структуру?

2) Что тут происходит? Мы инициализируем указатель на указатель? Чем тогда?

```
making = (struct in_addr **) test->h_addr_list;
```

3) `making[i]` - это стурктура или указатель? Или указатель на структуру?

4) Аргумент, который принимает функция `inet_ntoa()` является стуктура типа `in_addr`. Но мне все равно не совсем понятна запись -  `*making[i]`. Что она из себя представляет?

5) Зачем нам использовать данный цикл

```
for(i = 0; making[i] != NULL; i++){ 
        strcpy( buffer, inet_ntoa(*making[i])); 
}
```

нельзя было просто написать так

```
strcpy( buffer, inet_ntoa(*making[0]));
```

раз мы все равно берем только первый адрес

Заранее спасибо тем, кто ответит или хотя бы прочитает

Comment: Цикл понадобился именно для того, чтобы взять *последний* адрес, а не первый. Сделано странно - зачем копировать промежуточные адреса вхолостую? Но конечный итог именно таков: в buffer сохранится последний адрес.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) да,это указатель на указатель. Используют, что бы передать куда то указатель на массив для возможности его модификации (массив это также указатель).

2) приведение типа. В сетевом программировании это типичный прием. Инициализируем указатель на указатель неким адресом.

3) making - это указатель на указатель на структуру. `making[i]` - это указатель на структуру. `*making` - это также указатель на структуру. `**making` и `*making[i]` - это структура

4) В си  (и плюсах также) есть простое правило `a[b] == b[a] == *(a+b)` (то есть, эти 3 записи обозначают одно и тоже, их можно взаимозаменять. И конструкция `1["Hello"] - валидная и это просто буква`e`). Квадратные скобки "съедают одну звездочку".

в `test->h_addr_list` хранится не одно значение, а массив, который заканчивается NULL элементом (что бы не тянуть с собой ещё и размер, опять, типичный прием в сетевом программировании на сях). А конструкцией `*making[i]` просто извлекаем i элемент с массива и разыменовываем (что бы иметь значение, а не указатель)

5) Цикл используется, что бы пройтись по всем записям и взять нужную (в данном случае - последнюю). Вы ошибочно полагаете, что там будет только первая.

Но думаю, что в этом коде удалено часть тела цикла и там был вывод в консоль или проверка на условие (там ведь могут разные адреса быть и нужна небольшая фильтрация).

В целом, к сетевому программированию описываемая проблема отношение имеет относительное. Здесь загвоздка в непонимании работы с указателями на указатели.

Comment: меня начальник предупредил при поступлении на работу чтоб в коде больше 3х звездочек в ряд не было. Увы, пишем на с++, тут и одна звездочка - редкость. Вот народ и отвык.

Comment: когда то, когда я был юным программистом и две звездочки меня вводили в ступор, я просто аккуратно сделал typedef на указатель. И в результате указатель на указатель превратилось в указатель но этот тип.  И все стало сильно-сильно просто.

Comment: @KoVadim какой такой тип?) Указатель это скорее модификатор перменной чем типа.

Comment: вот так `typedef  int* array;`. И теперь можно писать так  `void foo(array * d) {}` и вызывать вот так `array x; foo(&x);`

Comment: "Указатель это скорее модификатор переменной чем типа" - это как это?